# Returning an object that is linked to a disposable one

Tags: c#, disposable

In the code below, does the disposal of `principalCtx` affect `userPrin`?

Is `principalCtx` just used to find the user or does it somehow stay linked to the `userPrin` object?

```
    UserPrincipal userPrin= null;
    using(PrincipalContext principalCtx as new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)){ 
        userPrin= UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalCtx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "first.last");
    }
    return userPrin;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `UserPrincipal` and `PrincipalContext` are disposable classes, which would suggest that their disposal is somewhat independent. *But* what I find in practice is that disposing of the `PrincipalContext` apparently *does* have some affect on the `UserPrincipal`. Although I am still able to access **properties** of the `UserPrincipal` after the `PrincipalContext` is disposed, if I try to call a **method** like `GetGroups()` on the `UserPrincipal` after the `PrincipalContext` is disposed, I get an error about trying to access a disposed object.

Keep in mind, though, that just because it has an effect doesn't mean that you shouldn't also separately dispose of the `UserPrincipal` object when you're done using it. There's no telling what separate resources `UserPrincipal` might need to clean up independently of the `PrincipalContext`.

So summary of suggestions to your code:

1. *Don't* try to access `userPrin` after `principalCtx` is disposed, or if you do, make sure you are only accessing properties that won't give you errors because I have verified that you can get errors by accessing methods after the context is disposed.
2. *Do* also dispose of `userPrin` or include it in a `using` block as well.

Comment: Since the `principalCtx` is passed by value to `FindByIdentity`, it can't retain a reference to it.

Comment: `PrincipalContext` is a reference type, so passing it by value only means that you are passing the reference by value. It's still just a reference to an object, which can be copied to refer to the same instance.

Comment: The calling method will dispose `userPrin`. However, if I remove the `using` from `PrincipalContext`, I guess that will not get disposed until GC is done.

Comment: I figure best way is to create a custom class that implements IDisposable and dispose of everything properly that way?

Comment: Could you copy the data that you need into a non-disposable object and return that instead? If not, your thought of encapsulating both the `UserPrincipal` and the `PrincipalContext` in a single object that can dispose of both a the same time is the best option I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Since `UserPrincipal` requires an instance of `PrincipalContext`, I wouldn't do that. Compare your code with this:

```
StreamReader reader;
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(@"c:\test.txt"))
{
    reader = new BinaryReader(input);
}

reader.Read();
```

Although we're talking `PrincipalContext` in this question, not files, the design is the same - you never know what the context is being used for under the hood.

Side note: `BinaryReader` actually has [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712804%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that lets you specify whether you're going to clean up or let `BinaryReader` do it for you.